# Query SQL with like operator from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

How can I do a SQL query with the `like` operator from two different tables?

I need something like:

```
select * from table1 where name like %table2.name
```

It's not a common field but a substring of a field on another table.

Comment: The more information you include in your question, the better the answers will be. This question provides very little information for people to work with.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? Both? Your question was originally only tagged SQL Server.

Comment: it's sql server...sorry!

Answer (score 4):

#### Edit

(original answer is further down)

Your comment (and subsequent edit) completely changes the question.

To do that, you can use `LIKE` as part of the `ON` clause in a join:

```
CREATE TABLE a (foo varchar(254))
GO

CREATE TABLE b (id int, bar varchar(254))
GO

INSERT INTO a (foo) VALUES ('one')
INSERT INTO a (foo) VALUES ('tone')
INSERT INTO a (foo) VALUES ('phone')
INSERT INTO a (foo) VALUES ('two')
INSERT INTO a (foo) VALUES ('three')

INSERT INTO b (id, bar) VALUES (2, 'ne')
INSERT INTO b (id, bar) VALUES (3, 't')

SELECT a.foo
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.foo LIKE '%' + b.bar
WHERE b.id = 2
```

(That's the SQL Server version; for MySQL, add in the various semicolons, remove the `GO`s, and use `...LIKE concat('%', b.bar)` instead.)

That uses `id` = 2 to find `bar` = "ne" in table `b`, then prepends the `%` operator and uses it to filter results from `a`. Results are:

```
one
tone
phone
```

You won't have to do the concat if you can store the operator in `b.bar`.

Separately, I was surprised to find that this works (on SQL Server) as well:

```
SELECT foo
FROM a
WHERE foo LIKE (
    SELECT TOP 1 '%' + bar
    FROM b
    WHERE id = 2
)
```

...but the version using `JOIN` is probably more flexible.

That should get you going.

#### Original answer

(Arguably no longer relevant)

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but here's an example of using `LIKE` to limit the results from a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.foo, b.bar
FROM someTable a
INNER JOIN someOtherTable b
    ON a.someField = b.someField
WHERE a.foo LIKE 'SOMETHING%'
AND b.bar LIKE '%SOMETHING ELSE'
```

That will give you `foo` from `someTable` and `bar` from `someOtherTable` where the rows are related by `someField` and `foo` starts with "SOMETHING" and `bar` ends with "SOMETHING ELSE".

Comment: i need something like: select * from table1 where name like %table2.name

Answer (score 3):

Not particularly sure about the precise syntax, but here's an idea:

```
select ... from (
    select ID, Foo as F from FooTable
    union all
    select ID, Bar as F from BarTable) R
where R.F like '%text%'
```

Comment: Your alias is `F`, so it should be `R.F like`, not `R.Foo like`.

Comment: it's not what i mean!! i nedd something like: select * from table1 where name like %table2.name

Comment: Would you be much better off putting the filter on the individual selects? You're creating a potentially huge result set as a union, and only then filtering. If you filter first, the statement will be less complex (eliminating a SELECT) and I'd think it would execute faster: `SELECT ID, Foo as F FROM FooTable WHERE Foo LIKE '%text%' UNION ALL SELECT ID, Bar as F FROM BarTable WHERE Bar LIKE '%text'`

Comment: no it's just filterin the content that is a substring of the one in another table

Comment: @simone: If so, this is not my fault. You should have been more precise in your original question. GIGO in its full glory :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @TJCrowder answer

### Test Tables

```
create table #A (
id varchar(10)
)


create table #b(
number varchar(5)
)

insert into #A values('123')
insert into #A values('456')
insert into #A values('789')
insert into #A values('0123')
insert into #A values('4567')

select * from #A

insert into #B values('12')
insert into #b values('45')
insert into #b values('987')
insert into #b values('012')
insert into #b values('666')
```

### Actual query

```
select * from #a, #b
where #a.id like '%' + #b.number + '%'
```

Modify the above query as you need such as

```
select #A.* from #A,#B ...
or
select * from #a, #b
where #a.id like  #b.number + '%'  -- one side match
```